# Instanciar Clase stdClass() y problema al imprimir

Tags: php

Quiero imprimir el valor del atributo std al llamar al método imprimir ya que estoy aprendiendo POO y estoy viendo el funcionamiento de la stdClass().

De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

```
<?php

class c {

    public $std;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->std = new stdClass();  
    }

    public function probando() 
    {
        $this->std->set = "hola";
    }
    public function imprimiendo() 
    {   echo "xdd";
        return $this->std->set;


    }

}

$x = new c;
echo $x->imprimiendo();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que mostras no estás llamando al método "probando", por lo que nunca se setea la clave "set" en el objeto.

```
$x = new c;
$x->probando();
echo $x->imprimiendo();
// hola
```